# Resize main partition with unallocated space in front

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Hi everyone I know there are couple of related questions but I have not found one that addresses it properly.

Problem: I have installed elementaryOS 0.4.1 Loki (Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS underneath) as a second OS on my laptop with Win 10 installed. Now after working for a while Linux is shifting to become my work horse and I wanted more space on the main partition for it. So I shrank the windows partition (from Windows with the built in Disk manager)
See below.

Problems:

1. I have found answers saying I need a live CD/USB and others saying that resizing is supported even while the partition is mounted. Which one is true?
2. Most answers have the allocated space in the back of main partition which seems to be no problem. When allocated space is in the front I have found varying answers. Some talking about remapping UUID and boot issues but provide no concrete steps ("Use gparted Live CD")

My main question: Is it possible to extend with the allocated space in front and how risky is it?

I know how to create live USB and somewhat use gParted but I'm not very familiar with the the UUID and boot procedure of linux.

Thanks for your help.

Gparted Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! I've edited your post to embed the Gparted screenshot :)

Answer (score 0):

1) yes you can extend toward the front. Essentially gparted does a move then grow.

2) Yes, a mounted partition can be extended. However, it does increase the risk of corruption and data loss. Always backup important data before doing any major file system changes.

3) An alternative that eliminates the risk to your current partition is to make a new partition in the free space. Then, set it up to automout to a folder in your file system.

Comment: Would I need to do any additional steps ( for example the remapping of UUID that I read somewhere) or will gparted take care of everything when moving and resizing?